# MySQL провайдер возвращает данные неполностью

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Доброго времени господа. Использую wpf DataGrid для отображения таблицы из БД MySQL. Проблема в том, что все столбцы в программе выводятся нормально и только один пустой, хотя в самой БД значения в этом столбце есть(тот же запрос в workBench возвращает полную таблицу).
 собственно код :

```
    public static DataTable ShowAllClient()
    {
        DataTable clients = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM orderholders";

            try
            {
                MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                adapter.SelectCommand = comm;
                conn.Open();
                adapter.Fill(clients);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            return clients;
        }
    }
```

в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Опишите может что за невозвращаемая колонка, какой тип и тд.

Comment: тип точно такой же как и у остальных колонок которые возвращаются. VARCHAR(45) NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что имя у колонки содержало "\"